# Show that $\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{g^{(n)}(c)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are functions such that
>
> - $f^{(k)}(c)=0$ and $g^{(k)}(c)=0$ for all $k=0,1,\dots,n-1$
> - $f^{(n)}$ and $g^{(n)}$ exist and are continuous
> - $g^{(n)}(c)\neq0$
>
> where $c\in I$. Show that
> $$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{g^{(n)}(c)}$$

My attempt:

Since $\frac{f^{(k)}(x)}{g^{(k)}(x)}$ is of an indeterminate form $\frac {0}{0}$ for $k\in \{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$, we can apply l'Hopital's rule $n$ times, i.e.,

$$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{g^{(n)}(x)}=\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{g^{(n)}(c)}.$$

Solved! But I can't help to think that there must be more to this question as it is a really major question in my homework set. And it has an inordinate amount of weightage to it.

Can anyone help me verify my proof?

Comment: Has L'Hospital's rule been proved? It looks a bit as if you are asked to prove that case of it.

Comment: If you've had L'Hospital, then this looks good.

Comment: "The limit being of the form 0/0" is not the only hypothesis that needs to be verified in order to apply L'Hospital.

Comment: Yup, Lhopital has been proven

Comment: Hans could you elaborate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also just use the Taylor theorem. By assumptions, $f(x)=f^{(n)}(c+\theta_f(x-c))\frac{(x-c)^n}{n!}$ and $g(x)=g^{(n)}(c+\theta_g(x-c))\frac{(x-c)^n}{n!}$, so that

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f^{(n)}(c+\theta_f(x-c))}{g^{(n)}(c+\theta_g(x-c))}$$

and in the limit $x\to c$ the result follows.

This could be made more stringent by recursively applying the extended mean value theorem.

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{g(x)-g(c)}=\frac{f'(x_1)}{g'(x_1)}=\frac{f'(x_1)-f'(c)}{g'(x_1)-g'(c)}=\frac{f''(x_2)}{g''(x_2)}=...$$